# add an action on a button without ibaction

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm working on a mapkit view, i added a button on an annotation like this:

```
UIButton *bt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[bt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = bt;
```

i want to go to another view (for example expleViewController) when touching that button, i'm  accustomed to do it using an IBAction method and link it with the button using Interface Builder, but this button is created manually, so how can I link it?

Comment: But next time please make the effort to read the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)b
{
    // do whatever you want ;)
}
```